# How to put this table in full page

Tags: tables

could you help me please
I want to put this table in full page .Itried without success

Thank you

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{colortbl}
 \usepackage{changepage}
 \usepackage{lscape}
 \usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}
\begin{sideways}
\begin{adjustwidth}{-4em}{-0.8em}
\scalebox{0.71}{
{\arraystrech{3pt}\arrayrulecolor{v3!20}
 \begin{tabular}{|>{\columncolor{gray!10} }*{27}{c|}|}

 \rowcolor{gray!10}&A&B&C&D&E&F&G&H&I&J&K&L&M&N&O&P&Q&R&S&T&U&V&W&X&Y\\ 
\rowcolor{gray!10} $i$& âge&sexe&taille&Bac&$Hc_{hab}$&$Hc_{veil}$&décal&$N_{for}$&$N{fat}$ &trav/sem&MoyBac&noteTU&mathsQ1&mathsQ2&mathsTotal&mathsQ1b&mathsQ2b&mathsTb&SpanC&SpanM&motsCo&motsLo&fluP&fluA&fluMoy \\
\rowcolor{gray!10} &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
 &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
1& \rowcolor{blue!10}    19&      1&      174&   T&    23&   24&   60&   2&  9&   5&  4& 0&  4&   0&   4&   C&   A&  A&6 &   4&  12& 9  &12    & 15  &13.5    \\
 \hline
2&     18&     2&      159&    L& 23.5& 23.75& 15&  3&     3&  20&  12&  10&   6&  4&  10&  D&  C&  C&  7&  4&  14& 10&  17&20 &18.5 \\
\hline
3& \rowcolor{blue!10}20&2&163&S&    23&1&120&1&11&15&15&11&7&5&12&D&C&C&5&5&10&8&13&18&15.5 \\
\hline
4&  22   & 1  &  151     &    L      &  22.5 &22.5  & 0    &  4&0 &10  &  8   &   3 &7     & 0  &7  &D    &A    & B  &  8&  5& 13   &10     &15   &   21 &  18   \\
\hline
5&\rowcolor{blue!10}24&1&190&E&22&22.75&15&4&0&10&8&2&4&0&4&C&A&A&7&5&9&6&13&16&14.5\\
\hline
6&18&2&165&L&22&23&60&2&8&15&11&9&5&4&9&C&C&B&7&4&15&11&12&22&17\\
\hline
7&\rowcolor{blue!10}17&2&157&T&22&22.5&30&3&5&20&9&6&3&3&6&B&B&B&6&5&12&8&12&17&14.5\\
\hline
8&30&2&160&S&22&22.75&45&3&6&5&10&7&7&4&11&D&C&C&8&6&14&10&14&19&16.5\\
\hline
9&\rowcolor{blue!10}19&1&175&S&23&23.25&45&2&9&20&16&14&6&5&11&D&C&C&6&4&11&8&15&20&17.5\\
\hline
10&20&2&176&L&23.25&1&105&1&9&5&4&0&6&0&6&D&A&B&6&4&12&9&13&23&18\\
\hline
11&\rowcolor{blue!10}19&2&160&S&23&0.25&75&1&10&5&8&6&7&0&7&D&A&B&7&5&12&10&16&18&17\\
\hline
12&18&2&162&S&23&24&60&2&8&20&16&15&7&7&14&D&D&C&8&4&15&12&13&19&16\\
\hline
13&\rowcolor{blue!10}17&1&178&L&22.5&23&30&3&4&15&14&12&7&5&12&D&C&C&7&4&13&9&15&24&19.5\\
\hline
14&18&1&185&S&23.5&0.75&75&1&11&15&15&11&6&5&12&D&C&C&7&5&13&10&14&20&17\\
\hline
15&\rowcolor{blue!10}19&2&167&L&23&23.25&15&4&2&10&7&2&6&2&8&D&B&B&6&4&10&6&16&25&20.5\\
\hline
16&18&2&162&T&22.5&23.75&75&2&9&10&6&1&2&1&3&B&A&A&7&5&12&8&12&16&14\\
\hline
17&\rowcolor{blue!10}17&2&160&S&22&22.5&30&3&4&15&10&7&7&3&10&D&B&C&8&6&13&9&15&18&16.5\\
\hline
18&20&1&178&S&23&23.15&10&3&5&20&14&13&6&5&11&D&C&C&7&4&13&10&15&19&17\\
\hline
19&\rowcolor{blue!10}19&1&182&S&22&23&60&2&7&15&10&5&7&2&9&D&B&B&6&5&10&7&16&20&18\\
\hline
20&18&2&166&E&22.5&23.5&60&2&8&5&2&0&6&0&6&D&A&B&6&4&10&7&13&18&15.5\\
\hline
21&\rowcolor{blue!10}19&2&170&L&22&22.75&45&2&8&20&12&9&6&5&11&D&C&C&8&6&15&11&14&20&17\\
\hline
22&20&2&158&T&23&0.5&90&1&10&5&1&0&4&0&4&C&A&A&7&5&12&8&16&15&15.5\\
\hline
23&\rowcolor{blue!10}19&1&172&S&23&24&60&2&9&15&11&7&7&6&13&D&B&C&6&4&12&8&13&18&15.5\\
\hline
24&18&1&190&L&22.5&23.05&60&2&8&20&15&10&5&2&7&C&B&B&5&4&11&8&14&21&17.5\\
\hline
25&\rowcolor{blue!10}19&2&156&L&21&21&0&4&1&5&6&1&6&0&6&D&A&B&7&5&12&9&15&22&18.5\\
\hline
26&20&1&180&L&23&1&120&1&9&15&9&6&6&1&7&D&A&B&7&4&11&7&17&23&20\\
\hline
27&\rowcolor{blue!10}19&2&167&L&23&23.25&45&2&9&15&8&5&7&1&8&D&A&B&8&6&14&10&16&24&20\\
\hline
28&18&1&186&S&22&22.5&30&3&3&20&14&12&7&7&14&D&D&C&7&5&10&7&14&19&16.5\\
\hline
29&\rowcolor{blue!10}26&2&165&L&22.25&22.75&30&3&5&10&11&6&7&2&9&D&B&B&7&4&13&9&13&25&19\\
\hline
30&19&2&168&L&23.5&0.5&60&2&10&15&13&10&6&5&11&D&C&C&5&3&10&6&14&20&17\\
\hline

 \end{tabular}}}

 \end{adjustwidth}
 \end{sideways}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please edit your code a bit more so that it becomes compilable. At present, there are error messages about undefined commands such as `\arraystrech` and undefined colors such as `v3`.

Comment: Sorry I have sent a wrong code!my problem is to put this table in full page ( changing marge only in this page) sorry for my bad english

Comment: Still can't compile.

Comment: @Trefex The code seems to be the same. I get multiple errors trying to compile...

Comment: @Haouam Before you post code, ***always compile it exactly as you intend to post it*** and do not post it until it compiles unless non-compilation is the topic of your question.

Answer (score 1):

I should say that I do **not** recommend this. It would be far preferable to rethink the presentation and produce a properly readable table. However, sometimes your hands are tied and needs must. If that is the case, here is a solution which fits the table on the page. I had to delete some parts of your code because they used definitions which were absent from the file you posted. I added `xcolor` but either you are using a package to define additional colours and I do not know what it is, or you are defining custom colours and I do not know what they are. Either way, it had to go.

[image: Table squished to page]

I think that the use of colours and rules is questionable and does you no favours, especially when space is this tight. I would recommend dispensing with one or the other since the colour tends to overwrite the rules in any case but does not do so consistently.

But for what it is worth, here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{array,xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
 \usepackage{changepage}
 \usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{adjustwidth}{-10em}{-0.8em}
\centering
\scalebox{0.71}{
 \begin{tabular}{|>{\columncolor{gray!10} }>{\cellcolor{gray!10}}c|*{26}{c|}|}
 \rowcolor{gray!10}&A&B&C&D&E&F&G&H&I&J&K&L&M&N&O&P&Q&R&S&T&U&V&W&X&Y\\
\rowcolor{gray!10} $i$& âge&sexe&taille&Bac&$Hc_{hab}$&$Hc_{veil}$&décal&$N_{for}$&$N{fat}$ &trav/sem&MoyBac&noteTU&mathsQ1&mathsQ2&mathsTotal&mathsQ1b&mathsQ2b&mathsTb&SpanC&SpanM&motsCo&motsLo&fluP&fluA&fluMoy \\[1em]\hline
\rowcolor{blue!10} 1&    19&      1&      174&   T&    23&   24&   60&   2&  9&   5&  4& 0&  4&   0&   4&   C&   A&  A&6 &   4&  12& 9  &12    & 15  &13.5    \\
 \hline
2&     18&     2&      159&    L& 23.5& 23.75& 15&  3&     3&  20&  12&  10&   6&  4&  10&  D&  C&  C&  7&  4&  14& 10&  17&20 &18.5 \\
\hline
\rowcolor{blue!10}3& 20&2&163&S&    23&1&120&1&11&15&15&11&7&5&12&D&C&C&5&5&10&8&13&18&15.5 \\
\hline
4&  22   & 1  &  151     &    L      &  22.5 &22.5  & 0    &  4&0 &10  &  8   &   3 &7     & 0  &7  &D    &A    & B  &  8&  5& 13   &10     &15   &   21 &  18   \\
\hline
\rowcolor{blue!10}5&24&1&190&E&22&22.75&15&4&0&10&8&2&4&0&4&C&A&A&7&5&9&6&13&16&14.5\\
\hline
6&18&2&165&L&22&23&60&2&8&15&11&9&5&4&9&C&C&B&7&4&15&11&12&22&17\\
\hline
\rowcolor{blue!10}7&17&2&157&T&22&22.5&30&3&5&20&9&6&3&3&6&B&B&B&6&5&12&8&12&17&14.5\\
\hline
8&30&2&160&S&22&22.75&45&3&6&5&10&7&7&4&11&D&C&C&8&6&14&10&14&19&16.5\\
\hline
\rowcolor{blue!10}9&19&1&175&S&23&23.25&45&2&9&20&16&14&6&5&11&D&C&C&6&4&11&8&15&20&17.5\\
\hline
10&20&2&176&L&23.25&1&105&1&9&5&4&0&6&0&6&D&A&B&6&4&12&9&13&23&18\\
\hline
\rowcolor{blue!10}11&19&2&160&S&23&0.25&75&1&10&5&8&6&7&0&7&D&A&B&7&5&12&10&16&18&17\\
\hline
12&18&2&162&S&23&24&60&2&8&20&16&15&7&7&14&D&D&C&8&4&15&12&13&19&16\\
\hline
\rowcolor{blue!10}13&17&1&178&L&22.5&23&30&3&4&15&14&12&7&5&12&D&C&C&7&4&13&9&15&24&19.5\\
\hline
14&18&1&185&S&23.5&0.75&75&1&11&15&15&11&6&5&12&D&C&C&7&5&13&10&14&20&17\\
\hline
\rowcolor{blue!10}15&19&2&167&L&23&23.25&15&4&2&10&7&2&6&2&8&D&B&B&6&4&10&6&16&25&20.5\\
\hline
16&18&2&162&T&22.5&23.75&75&2&9&10&6&1&2&1&3&B&A&A&7&5&12&8&12&16&14\\
\hline
\rowcolor{blue!10}17&17&2&160&S&22&22.5&30&3&4&15&10&7&7&3&10&D&B&C&8&6&13&9&15&18&16.5\\
\hline
18&20&1&178&S&23&23.15&10&3&5&20&14&13&6&5&11&D&C&C&7&4&13&10&15&19&17\\
\hline
\rowcolor{blue!10}19&19&1&182&S&22&23&60&2&7&15&10&5&7&2&9&D&B&B&6&5&10&7&16&20&18\\
\hline
20&18&2&166&E&22.5&23.5&60&2&8&5&2&0&6&0&6&D&A&B&6&4&10&7&13&18&15.5\\
\hline
\rowcolor{blue!10}21&19&2&170&L&22&22.75&45&2&8&20&12&9&6&5&11&D&C&C&8&6&15&11&14&20&17\\
\hline
22&20&2&158&T&23&0.5&90&1&10&5&1&0&4&0&4&C&A&A&7&5&12&8&16&15&15.5\\
\hline
\rowcolor{blue!10}23&19&1&172&S&23&24&60&2&9&15&11&7&7&6&13&D&B&C&6&4&12&8&13&18&15.5\\
\hline
24&18&1&190&L&22.5&23.05&60&2&8&20&15&10&5&2&7&C&B&B&5&4&11&8&14&21&17.5\\
\hline
\rowcolor{blue!10}25&19&2&156&L&21&21&0&4&1&5&6&1&6&0&6&D&A&B&7&5&12&9&15&22&18.5\\
\hline
26&20&1&180&L&23&1&120&1&9&15&9&6&6&1&7&D&A&B&7&4&11&7&17&23&20\\
\hline
\rowcolor{blue!10}27&19&2&167&L&23&23.25&45&2&9&15&8&5&7&1&8&D&A&B&8&6&14&10&16&24&20\\
\hline
28&18&1&186&S&22&22.5&30&3&3&20&14&12&7&7&14&D&D&C&7&5&10&7&14&19&16.5\\
\hline
\rowcolor{blue!10}29&26&2&165&L&22.25&22.75&30&3&5&10&11&6&7&2&9&D&B&B&7&4&13&9&13&25&19\\
\hline
30&19&2&168&L&23.5&0.5&60&2&10&15&13&10&6&5&11&D&C&C&5&3&10&6&14&20&17\\
\hline
 \end{tabular}}
 \end{adjustwidth}
 \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here another way of doing things, without vertical lines, but keeping a frame, so that decimal numbers are aligned to the decimal marker while centred in their columns. As to the column heads, I split them into the letter part, and the rest, which is rotated. This way you can put te whole table on the page with a `\small` font without scaling. The vertical (i.e. horizontal adjustment is done through the value of `\tabcolsep`). The horizontal (vertical) adjustment is done through the use of the `cellspace` package, thus giving a better vertical spacing for the table rows .

In addition to cellspace, it requires loading `xstring`, `mathtools`, `rotating` and `numprint`.

```
\documentclass[a4pape]{article}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}

 \usepackage[margin=2.5cm, ,nomarginpar, showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{array, mathtools}

\usepackage[table, svgnames, x11names]{xcolor}
 \usepackage{changepage}
 \usepackage{lscape, rotating}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage[autolanguage]{numprint}
\newcolumntype{I}{n{2}{0}}
\newcolumntype{J}{n{3}{0}}

\usepackage{xstring}
 \newcommand\myhead[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\clap{\textbf{\StrLeft{#1}{1}}}\rlap{\rotatebox[origin =lt]{40}{\hskip0.5em\StrGobbleLeft{#1}{1}}}}}%

 \usepackage{cellspace}
 \setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{4pt}
 \setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{4pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{8pt}\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1.2pt}
\rowcolors{2}{blue!10}{}\arrayrulecolor{Thistle3}%
\small\centering
 \begin{tabular}{|>{\columncolor{gray!10}}Sr*{4}{c}*{2}{n{2}{2}}n{3}{0}c*{4}{I}ccI*{5}{c}*{4}{I}n{2}{1}|}%2
\multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{\boldmath$ i $}& \myhead{A âge} & \myhead{B sexe} & \myhead{C\enspace taille} & \myhead{D Bac} & \myhead{E Hc$_{\text{hab}}$} & \myhead{F Hc$_{\text{veil}}$} & \myhead{G décal} & \myhead{H N$_{\text{for}}$} & \myhead{I N$_{\text{fat}}$} &\myhead{J trav/sem} & \myhead{K MoyBac} & \myhead{L noteTU} & \myhead{M mathsQ1} & \myhead{NmathsQ2} & \myhead{O mathsTotal} & \myhead{P mathsQ1b} & \myhead{Q mathsQ2b} & \myhead{R mathsTb} & \myhead{S SpanC} & \myhead{T SpanM} &\myhead{U motsCo} & \myhead{V motsLo} & \myhead{W fluP} & \myhead{X fluA} & \myhead{Y fluMoy}
 \\[0.5ex]
 \hline
 1 & 19 & 1 & 174 & T & 23 & 24 & 60 & 2 & 9 & 5 & 4 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 4 & C & A & A & 6 & 4 & 12 & 9 & 12 & 15 & 13.5 \\
%
2 & 18 & 2 & 159 & L & 23.5 & 23.75 & 15 & 3 & 3 & 20 & 12 & 10 & 6 & 4 & 10 & D & C & C & 7 & 4 & 14 & 10 & 17 & 20 & 18.5 \\
%
3 &20 & 2 & 163 & S & 23 & 1 & 120 & 1 & 11 & 15 & 15 & 11 & 7 & 5 & 12 & D & C & C & 5 & 5 & 10 & 8 & 13 & 18 & 15.5 \\
%
4 & 22 & 1 & 151 & L & 22.5 & 22.5 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 10 & 8 & 3 & 7 & 0 & 7 & D & A & B & 8 & 5 & 13 & 10 & 15 & 21 & 18 \\
%
5 & 24 & 1 & 190 & E & 22 & 22.75 & 15 & 4 & 0 & 10 & 8 & 2 & 4 & 0 & 4 & C & A & A & 7 & 5 & 9 & 6 & 13 & 16 & 14.5\\
%
6 & 18 & 2 & 165 & L & 22 & 23 & 60 & 2 & 8 & 15 & 11 & 9 & 5 & 4 & 9 & C & C & B & 7 & 4 & 15 & 11 & 12 & 22 & 17\\
%
\ 7 & 17 & 2 & 157 & T & 22 & 22.5 & 30 & 3 & 5 & 20 & 9 & 6 & 3 & 3 & 6 & B & B & B & 6 & 5 & 12 & 8 & 12 & 17 & 14.5\\
%
8 & 30 & 2 & 160 & S & 22 & 22.75 & 45 & 3 & 6 & 5 & 10 & 7 & 7 & 4 & 11 & D & C & C & 8 & 6 & 14 & 10 & 14 & 19 & 16.5\\
%
9 & 19 & 1 & 175 & S & 23 & 23.25 & 45 & 2 & 9 & 20 & 16 & 14 & 6 & 5 & 11 & D & C & C & 6 & 4 & 11 & 8 & 15 & 20 & 17.5\\
%
10 & 20 & 2 & 176 & L & 23.25 & 1 & 105 & 1 & 9 & 5 & 4 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 6 & D & A & B & 6 & 4 & 12 & 9 & 13 & 23 & 18\\
%
 11 & 19 & 2 & 160 & S & 23 & 0.25 & 75 & 1 & 10 & 5 & 8 & 6 & 7 & 0 & 7 & D & A & B & 7 & 5 & 12 & 10 & 16 & 18 & 17\\
%
12 & 18 & 2 & 162 & S & 23 & 24 & 60 & 2 & 8 & 20 & 16 & 15 & 7 & 7 & 14 & D & D & C & 8 & 4 & 15 & 12 & 13 & 19 & 16\\
%
 13 & 17 & 1 & 178 & L & 22.5 & 23 & 30 & 3 & 4 & 15 & 14 & 12 & 7 & 5 & 12 & D & C & C & 7 & 4 & 13 & 9 & 15 & 24 & 19.5\\
%
14 & 18 & 1 & 185 & S & 23.5 & 0.75 & 75 & 1 & 11 & 15 & 15 & 11 & 6 & 5 & 12 & D & C & C & 7 & 5 & 13 & 10 & 14 & 20 & 17\\
%
15 & 19 & 2 & 167 & L & 23 & 23.25 & 15 & 4 & 2 & 10 & 7 & 2 & 6 & 2 & 8 & D & B & B & 6 & 4 & 10 & 6 & 16 & 25 & 20.5\\
%
16 & 18 & 2 & 162 & T & 22.5 & 23.75 & 75 & 2 & 9 & 10 & 6 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 3 & B & A & A & 7 & 5 & 12 & 8 & 12 & 16 & 14\\
%
17 & 17 & 2 & 160 & S & 22 & 22.5 & 30 & 3 & 4 & 15 & 10 & 7 & 7 & 3 & 10 & D & B & C & 8 & 6 & 13 & 9 & 15 & 18 & 16.5\\
%
18 & 20 & 1 & 178 & S & 23 & 23.15 & 10 & 3 & 5 & 20 & 14 & 13 & 6 & 5 & 11 & D & C & C & 7 & 4 & 13 & 10 & 15 & 19 & 17\\
%
19 & 19 & 1 & 182 & S & 22 & 23 & 60 & 2 & 7 & 15 & 10 & 5 & 7 & 2 & 9 & D & B & B & 6 & 5 & 10 & 7 & 16 & 20 & 18\\
%
20 & 18 & 2 & 166 & E & 22.5 & 23.5 & 60 & 2 & 8 & 5 & 2 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 6 & D & A & B & 6 & 4 & 10 & 7 & 13 & 18 & 15.5\\
%
21 & 19 & 2 & 170 & L & 22 & 22.75 & 45 & 2 & 8 & 20 & 12 & 9 & 6 & 5 & 11 & D & C & C & 8 & 6 & 15 & 11 & 14 & 20 & 17\\
%
22 & 20 & 2 & 158 & T & 23 & 0.5 & 90 & 1 & 10 & 5 & 1 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 4 & C & A & A & 7 & 5 & 12 & 8 & 16 & 15 & 15.5\\
%
23 & 19 & 1 & 172 & S & 23 & 24 & 60 & 2 & 9 & 15 & 11 & 7 & 7 & 6 & 13 & D & B & C & 6 & 4 & 12 & 8 & 13 & 18 & 15.5\\
%
24 & 18 & 1 & 190 & L & 22.5 & 23.05 & 60 & 2 & 8 & 20 & 15 & 10 & 5 & 2 & 7 & C & B & B & 5 & 4 & 11 & 8 & 14 & 21 & 17.5\\
%
25 & 19 & 2 & 156 & L & 21 & 21 & 0 & 4 & 1 & 5 & 6 & 1 & 6 & 0 & 6 & D & A & B & 7 & 5 & 12 & 9 & 15 & 22 & 18.5\\
%
26 & 20 & 1 & 180 & L & 23 & 1 & 120 & 1 & 9 & 15 & 9 & 6 & 6 & 1 & 7 & D & A & B & 7 & 4 & 11 & 7 & 17 & 23 & 20\\
%
27 & 19 & 2 & 167 & L & 23 & 23.25 & 45 & 2 & 9 & 15 & 8 & 5 & 7 & 1 & 8 & D & A & B & 8 & 6 & 14 & 10 & 16 & 24 & 20\\
%
28 & 18 & 1 & 186 & S & 22 & 22.5 & 30 & 3 & 3 & 20 & 14 & 12 & 7 & 7 & 14 & D & D & C & 7 & 5 & 10 & 7 & 14 & 19 & 16.5\\
%
29 & 26 & 2 & 165 & L & 22.25 & 22.75 & 30 & 3 & 5 & 10 & 11 & 6 & 7 & 2 & 9 & D & B & B & 7 & 4 & 13 & 9 & 13 & 25 & 19\\
%
30 & 19 & 2 & 168 & L & 23.5 & 0.5 & 60 & 2 & 10 & 15 & 13 & 10 & 6 & 5 & 11 & D & C & C & 5 & 3 & 10 & 6 & 14 & 20 & 17\\
\hline
 \end{tabular}%
 \end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, that's what I want . However if I want that only this page is concerned by margins what's the best way to do so? (sorry for my bad english)

Comment: You can use this command from the  `geometry`package: \newgeometry{margin=2.5cm,nomarginpar,showframe}` just before entering the sidewaystable environment, and `\restore{geometry}` just after leaving it. Offside: I don't think I can write in French on this site, except perhaps on chat, since comments/questions/answers are supposed to be helpful for everyone…